# If statement with || is not doing anything

Tags: javascript

some context,
I'm making a game wherein you have to guess a randomly generated number between 1 and 1 million. I'm trying to make it so that if the user inputs something that is not a number, above 1 million, or below zero, it will display an error warning. The last else if statement is supposed to do this, but is not doing so. I've tried several revisions, including individual else if statements for each forbidden case, but they aren't working.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000 + 1);
    var count = 0;
    var x = 1000000
    console.log(randomNumber)
    document.getElementById("submitguess").onclick = function(){    
    var userGuess = document.getElementById("guessField").value;
    console.log(userGuess)
    if(userGuess == randomNumber)
    {    
        if (count < 10) {
            document.getElementById('higherOrLower').innerHTML = '<div class="powerupstyling"><a class="facethebossstyling">YOU BEAT THE GAME. CONGRATS !</a></div>'
        }
        else if (count > 10) {
            document.getElementById('higherOrLower').innerHTML = "<center>grats you got it in " + count + " tries. Unfortunately, you didn't quite beat the game. Aim for 10 tries or lower.</center>"
        }
        
        
    }
    else if (userGuess > randomNumber) {    
        count++;
        document.getElementById('higherOrLower').innerHTML = '<br><div class="powerupstyling"><a class="gostyling">go lower</a></div>'
        document.getElementById('countCounter').innerHTML = "<center>tries: " + count + "</center>";
       
    }
    else if (userGuess < randomNumber) {
        count++;
        document.getElementById('higherOrLower').innerHTML = '<br><div class="powerupstyling"><a class="gostyling">go higher</a></div>'
        document.getElementById('countCounter').innerHTML = "<center>tries: " + count + "</center>";
    }
    else if (userGuess >= 1000000 || userGuess =< 0 || userGuess == "") {
        alert('input a valid number !')
    }
}
</script
```

Comment: `userGuess =< 0` is invalid syntax. (We had the same syntax error just [2 days ago](/q/67858351/4642212), interestingly…)

Comment: Each of the above 3 conditions cover all cases. You'll want to check the last one before the others.

Comment: The input validation should be done first before comparing the input with radon number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write the last `else if` before you check if the `userGuess` is higher or lower than the `randomNumber`.

That's because when `userGuess` is below 0 or over 1.000.000 it will always be catched by the `else if`s that check if the `userGuess` is lower or higher than `randomNumber`. Therefore the last `else if` will never be reached.

---

The correct order would be:

1. Check if the user guessed right.
2. **Check if the input is wrong.**
3. Check if the user guessed too high.
4. Check if the user guessed too low.

But you did:

1. Check if the user guessed right.
2. Check if the user guessed too high.
3. Check if the user guessed too low.
4. **Check if the input is wrong.**

---

Do the following:

```js
<script type = "text/javascript">
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000 + 1);
    var count = 0;
    var x = 1000000
    console.log(randomNumber)
    document.getElementById("submitguess").onclick = function(){    
    var userGuess = document.getElementById("guessField").value;
    console.log(userGuess)
    if(userGuess == randomNumber)
    {    
        if (count < 10) {
            document.getElementById('higherOrLower').innerHTML = '<div class="powerupstyling"><a class="facethebossstyling">YOU BEAT THE GAME. CONGRATS !</a></div>'
        }
        else if (count > 10) {
            document.getElementById('higherOrLower').innerHTML = "<center>grats you got it in " + count + " tries. Unfortunately, you didn't quite beat the game. Aim for 10 tries or lower.</center>"
        }
        
        
    }
    else if (userGuess >= 1000000 || userGuess <= 0 || userGuess == "") {
        alert('input a valid number !')
    }
    else if (userGuess > randomNumber) {    
        count++;
        document.getElementById('higherOrLower').innerHTML = '<br><div class="powerupstyling"><a class="gostyling">go lower</a></div>'
        document.getElementById('countCounter').innerHTML = "<center>tries: " + count + "</center>";
       
    }
    else if (userGuess < randomNumber) {
        count++;
        document.getElementById('higherOrLower').innerHTML = '<br><div class="powerupstyling"><a class="gostyling">go higher</a></div>'
        document.getElementById('countCounter').innerHTML = "<center>tries: " + count + "</center>";
    }
    
}
</script
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple problems with your conditionals.

```
else if (userGuess > randomNumber) 
{ ... }
```

This will handle all numbers, even those greater than 1,000,000.

```
else if (userGuess < randomNumber)
{ ... }
```

This will handle all numbers, even those less than 0.

Therefore, your last conditional will only ever catch a blank input (which would probably be better expressed as a cast to string or bool).

Also, as pointed out in the comments to your question, the correct `less than or equal` syntax is `<=`.

Answer (score 0):

You do:

```js
else if (userGuess >= 1000000 || userGuess =< 0 || userGuess == "") {
```

But it's like this:

```js
else if (userGuess >= 1000000 || userGuess <= 0 || userGuess == "") {
```

```html
<script type = "text/javascript">
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000 + 1);
    var count = 0;
    var x = 1000000
    console.log(randomNumber)
    document.getElementById("submitguess").onclick = function(){    
    var userGuess = document.getElementById("guessField").value;
    console.log(userGuess)
    if(userGuess == randomNumber)
    {    
        if (count < 10) {
            document.getElementById('higherOrLower').innerHTML = '<div class="powerupstyling"><a class="facethebossstyling">YOU BEAT THE GAME. CONGRATS !</a></div>'
        }
        else if (count > 10) {
            document.getElementById('higherOrLower').innerHTML = "<center>grats you got it in " + count + " tries. Unfortunately, you didn't quite beat the game. Aim for 10 tries or lower.</center>"
        }
        
        
    }
    else if (userGuess > randomNumber) {    
        count++;
        document.getElementById('higherOrLower').innerHTML = '<br><div class="powerupstyling"><a class="gostyling">go lower</a></div>'
        document.getElementById('countCounter').innerHTML = "<center>tries: " + count + "</center>";
       
    }
    else if (userGuess < randomNumber) {
        count++;
        document.getElementById('higherOrLower').innerHTML = '<br><div class="powerupstyling"><a class="gostyling">go higher</a></div>'
        document.getElementById('countCounter').innerHTML = "<center>tries: " + count + "</center>";
    }
    else if (userGuess >= 1000000 || userGuess <= 0 || userGuess == "") {
        alert('input a valid number !')
    }
}
</script
```

Comment: Still won't catch the `userGuess` being over 1,000,000 or less than 0.